# What's the right phrase for this situation? yell for, shout for, call someone or whatever

Tags: word-choice

Someone I know is walking across the street. In order to gain her or his attention I called the name loudly. What phrase should I use in this situation?  I remembered once a native speaker said like this, "I have to shout for my husband." At that time her husband was downstairs. But I might be wrong, because I cannnot find this expression in any dictionary. I found the phrase "yell for help" but not "yell for someone".   Could you tell me which phrase is most appropriate here?  Can I also say like, "I called my friend loudly on the street." or "I called my friend's name loudly."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also say

> I called *to* her across the street to get her attention.
>
> I shouted *to* her to get her attention.
>
> I yelled *to* her  to get her attention.

To **shout *for* someone** means to summon them loudly, especially in an urgent situation.

> The ladder slipped out from under me. I managed to grab onto the
>   window ledge and had to shout for my son.

Ditto, yell for s.o., call for s.o.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know. It is very clear and helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you say "shout his name" instead of "shout for him"? Would it be okay?

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi  To "shout someone's name" does not explicitly express *intention*; it merely refers to the action of shouting something, in this case, a name; whereas to "shout *for* someone" expresses the intention of *summoning* the person,   as when calling for help, say, or calling someone to come and look at something they might be interested in. "The big televised match was about to begin so he *shouted for his mates* who were still out in the garden."

Comment: @Tim Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The word [hail](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hail) is exactly what you are looking for, but it is not widely used. The definition is *to call someone in order to attract their attention*.

Here are a couple of examples:

> Shall we hail a taxi?
>   I tried to hail her from across the room